# How to deal with convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{ \lfloor{\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}} \rfloor } \cdot \frac{\log(n)}{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have a small problem to check convergence of expression like that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{\left \lfloor{\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}}\right \rfloor } \cdot \frac{\log(n)}{n} $$ 
On my lessons usually we have situations when $\sum_{n=1} \left| u_n \right|$ converges and then from the criterion of absolute convergence  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n $ converges too. Ok, it is simple. Other situation is when I have something with regular behavior for example $ (-1)^n \cdot sth $
But there I have totally hard to predict and catch some rules expression and how can I check convergence of that? Of course the sum can be conditionally convergent but what next to be done there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A first simplification: Observing that $$\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} = \frac{n}{3}+o(1)$$ we have $$\left\lfloor \frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$$ for $n$ large enough. Therefore, it is enough to study $$\sum_n (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} \frac{\log n}{n}$$
- To deal with this (obviously, as you noted we do not have absolute convergence), note that the sign is constant for triples: $3k,3k+1,3k+2$. I.e., 
  $$
  \sum_{n=3}^{3N} (-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor} \frac{\log n}{n}
  = \sum_{k=1}^{N} (-1)^{k} \underbrace{\sum_{n=3k}^{3k+2}\frac{\log n}{n}}_{v_k}
  $$
  Can you use some theorem you know to study the convergence of $\sum_{k}(-1)^k v_k$?

  *(For instance, first you may want to show that $(v_k)_k$ is decreasing.)*

Comment: Note: the very first step needs a bit of elaboration. Namely, what is in thr $o(1)$ is positive, so it does not alter the result of the floor when $n$ is a multple of 3.

Comment: Note that the tested series is alternating. It's known that $\left| u_{n+1} \right| \le \left| u_{n} \right|$
for sufficiently large n.
but we know that $lim u_n = 0$ by the Leibniz criterion the series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Ok, I have understand this solution, It is very interesting! Thanks for your time!